# want to show a background color through this ng-tamplate

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular6, ng-template

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvkT2.png)Here is my code with this ng-template ngFor let c of colors generate some internal html tag which can i can not add the property of css.

```
 <ng-template *ngFor="let c of colors" contextMenuItem let-item (execute)="change_task_color($event.item.task_id,c.user_color_id,$event.item)">{{c.name}}</ng-template>
```

The code genrated thorugh this upper line is

```
<div _ngcontent-c14="" class="dropdown open show ngx-contextmenu" tabindex="0" ng-reflect-klass="dropdown open show ngx-context" ng-reflect-ng-class="">
                  <ul _ngcontent-c14="" class="dropdown-menu show" style="position: static; float: none;" tabindex="0">
                    <li _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                        <a _ngcontent-c14="" href="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                        Red
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                        <a _ngcontent-c14="" href="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                        Blue
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                        <a _ngcontent-c14="" href="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                        Yellow
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                        <a _ngcontent-c14="" href="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                        White
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                        <a _ngcontent-c14="" href="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                        Purple
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                        <a _ngcontent-c14="" href="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                        Orange
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                        <a _ngcontent-c14="" href="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                        Green
                        </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
```

Comment: Why are you using ng-template ? Any reason at all ?

Comment: this code is not written by me  i want to add background color in anchor tag through ng tamplate

Comment: Create an Input, something like `[color]="c"`, and manage it in your component to apply it where you want with `[style.background]="color"`

Comment: not understand how ??

Comment: You have a `ContextMenuItemComponent`, right ?

Comment: yes correct !!!

Comment: Then put an input in it, that will be the color

Comment: with this how i can addd background color in <a _ngcontent-c14="" href="" class="ng-star-inserted"> Green </a> this tag

Comment: I'm not coding for you, I'm not here for that. I told you how to resolve your issue, now go ahead and try.

Comment: Not **REsolved**

Comment: thanks in advance but i cant get any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, with the help of loop i add class with index count the every li tag get their own class after call the function and set the background color with the help of j-query add css .